# Prove that $f(x)=(x,2x+1,3x+2,4x+3,\ldots)$ is noT continuous.

Tags: general-topology

Consider the function $ f: \Bbb R \to \prod_ {n \in \mathbb Z ^+} \Bbb R $ given by, $$f(x)=(x,2x+1,3x+2,4x+3,\ldots).$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$, where $ \mathbb R $ has the standard topology, $ \prod_ {n \in \mathbb Z ^ +} \Bbb R $ has the box topology. Is $ f $ continuous?

**My Try**.

I think that $ f $ is not continuous. First note that the $ n $-th coordinate of the function is $ f_n: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $, $ f_n (x) = nx + (n-1) $. If I consider the following intervals, $$ A = (- 1,1) \times (0,2) \times \cdots = \prod_ {n \in \mathbb Z ^ +} ((n-1) -1, ( n-1)+1).$$But I need to show that $ f ^ {- 1} (A) $ is not open. I know that $ f ^ {- 1} (A) = \{0 \} $ which is not open with the standard topology, but how do I prove that? Some help

Comment: It looks to me like you have it all figured out. What part specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Oh, are you having trouble proving that $f^{-1}(A) = \{0\}$?

Comment: Yeah, thats my problem. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \in f^{-1}[A]$ iff

$f(x) \in A = \prod_{n \in \Bbb Z^+} ((n-1)-1, (n-1)+1)$ iff

$\forall n \in \Bbb Z^+: f_n(x) \in \left((n-1)-1, (n-1)+1\right)$ iff

$\forall n \in \Bbb Z^+: (n-1) - 1 < nx + (n-1) < (n-1)+1$ iff

$\forall n \in \Bbb Z^+: -1 < nx < 1$ iff

$\forall n \in \Bbb Z^+: -\frac1n < x < \frac1n$ iff

$x=0$.

So $f^{-1}[A]=\{0\}$ which is *not* open in $\Bbb R$.